# Quickfix window not displaying stderr messages?

Tags: vimrc, quickfix

After running `:make`, the quickfix window displays the compile command and other `stdout` messages from the makefile, but it doesn't display any errors. Everything but `stderr` messages are displaying. How do I enable `stderr` messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add this to your vimrc:

```
set shellpipe=2>
```

...to enable `stderr` output in the quickfix window.

Answer (score 2):

To collect *only* stderr, use:

```
set shellpipe=2>
```

To collect *both* stderr and stdout:

```
set shellpipe=>%s\ 2>&1
```

Or, to collect both and watch builds as they proceed:

```
set shellpipe=2>&1\ \|\ tee
```